# Mixed models: do I include a group var as a random effect if several fixed-effect vars describe the groups?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Each of a random sample of subjects rated a random sub-sample from a random sample of items.

Thus, both subjects and items are grouping variables for individual observations.

The primary interest is finding out the effect of different properties of items on the output variable(s).

*Do I need to include items as a random effect if the model also contains one/several of item properties as fixed-effect variables?*

I'm very confused about this question, since it's easy with subjects - I don't care for the inter-subject differences and account for the differences with a random-effect variable. But with items, I'm exactly interested in how inter-item differences affected the outcome. Should I still include items as a random effect?

---

EDIT: Below are the samples of data to understand the question better.

Should the model be M1 or M2?:

M1 =  readingTime ~ webpageFontSize * ageGroup * langGroup + (1|subjectID);

M2 = readingTime ~ webpageFontSize * ageGroup * langGroup + (1|subjectID) + (1|webpageID);

```
'data.frame':   394 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ webpageID      : Factor w/ 50 levels "141b944b","14b29e31",..: 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 34 34 34 ...
 $ readingTime    : num  -0.21 1.393 2.808 0.407 0.436 ...
 $ subjectID      : Factor w/ 79 levels "ACA00210","ACA01610",..: 37 39 61 58 78 21 10 67 12 42 ...
 $ ageGroup       : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","K": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ langGroup      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ webpageFontSize: num  0.302 0.302 0.302 0.302 0.302 ...

>   myDat1[1:10,]
   webpageID readingTime subjectID ageGroup langGroup webpageFontSize
1   f877810f  -0.2102541  JVK00709        K         0       0.3019308
2   f877810f   1.3925645  KTK00911        K         0       0.3019308
3   f877810f   2.8082266  PDK11311        K         1       0.3019308
4   f877810f   0.4074548  NCA02211        A         0       0.3019308
5   f877810f   0.4363652  VSA12310        A         1       0.3019308
6   f877810f  -0.3392786  FPA12501        A         1       0.3019308
7   f877810f   0.3297732  CMA01210        A         0       0.3019308
8   aec261da   0.1864803  SGK01011        K         0      -1.4319861
9   aec261da  -0.4739890  DBA01210        A         0      -1.4319861
10  aec261da   1.3601557  LBK00910        K         0      -1.4319861

>   myDat1[order(myDat1[,"subjectID"]),][1:10,]
    webpageID readingTime subjectID ageGroup langGroup webpageFontSize
291  fd4a7f29  -0.4584633  ACA00210        A         0       0.7748173
303  2a1f67ab  -0.4487744  ACA00210        A         0       0.7748173
315  2d9ebbb2  -0.5552781  ACA00210        A         0       0.7748173
357  d3e8bd12  -0.4230263  ACA00210        A         0       0.6171885
363  bc585e39  -0.8482511  ACA00210        A         0       0.5383740
113  9bb56961 -0.36192924  ADK00311        K         0       0.1127763
168   6075c56  0.10060895  ADK00311        K         0       0.6171885
302  2a1f67ab -0.87750259  ADK00311        K         0       0.7748173
317  2d9ebbb2 -0.23837682  ADK00311        K         0       0.7748173
389  6a7ef88c -0.53135570  ADK00311        K         0       0.7748173
```

Comment: It's hard to say from the information given.  it sounds like you need *crossed* random effects - that is, random intercepts for both subjects and items.  Could you  elaborate more on the experimental design and perhaps include a the output from `str(mydata)`?

Comment: Let's say the items are webpages; an item property is webpage font size; and outcome is reading time. 

`m1 = readingTime ~ fontSize + (1|SubjectID)`

`m2 = readingTime ~ fontSize + (1|SubjectID) + (1|WebpageID)`

Can I use m1, or better m2?

Comment: It is hard to say, can you post that code along with `str(data)` and a crosstab of `subjectID` with `WebpageID` into the question.?

Comment: @RobertLong, I'm not sure what you meant with crosstab. Could you specify?

Comment: Never mind about that now. I can see there are too many levels for it to be helpful.